# How to play Text Tone from HTML5 app in iPhone

Tags: iphone, html

How do I play a iphone Text tone from my application that's running on safari browser?

Answer (score 0):

I believe Mobile Safari outputs the contents of the HTML5 `<audio>` tag via the separate iOS media player. If you want audio *within* your webpage, take a look at [jPlayer](http://www.jplayer.org), a jQuery plug-in for audio.